# How to insert date as child name in Firebase database and add an array

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, datetime, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a basic app where I add information to a Firebase database. I have three fields and a date. I would like add the date from EditText as the child name in Firebase, instead of writing it in the code. Something like in the picture below:

[image]

What I have now is a code that generates the same table again and again (like in the left hand side), because I can't manage to build an array. So I'm asking for help to generate such an array when the "BUTTON" button in clicked (See picture below).

[image]

In addition to generating an array, I would like that each child would have instead of the string "Date", the date coming from the EditText in the layout (right hand side of the picture).

So far I have this basic code:

MainActivity.java

```js
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText date, text_field2, text_field3, text_field4;
  Button send_button;
  User user;
  FirebaseDatabase database; // = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  DatabaseReference myRef; // = database.getReference();



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
    text_field2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field2);
    text_field3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field3);
    text_field4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field4);
    send_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("User");
    user = new User();
  }

  private void getValues() {
    user.setDate(date.getText().toString());
    user.setField2(text_field2.getText().toString());
    user.setField3(text_field3.getText().toString());
    user.setField4(text_field4.getText().toString());
  }

  public void Send(View view) {
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        getValues();
        /*String UID = Array.getUID();
        myRef.child(UID).setValue(user);*/
        myRef.child("Date").setValue(user);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
    });
  }

}
```

User.java

```js
//User has to be the same as the first folder
public class User {
  private String Date, Field2, Field3, Field4, UID;

  public User() {}


  public User(String date, String field2, String field3, String field4, String UID) {
    Date = date;
    Field2 = field2;
    Field3 = field3;
    Field4 = field4;
    this.UID = UID;

  }

  public String getDate() {
    return Date;
  }

  public void setDate(String date) {
    Date = date;
  }

  public String getField2() {
    return Field2;
  }

  public void setField2(String field2) {
    Field2 = field2;
  }

  public String getField3() {
    return Field3;
  }

  public void setField3(String field3) {
    Field3 = field3;
  }

  public String getField4() {
    return Field4;
  }

  public void setField4(String field4) {
    Field4 = field4;
  }

  public String getUID() {
    return UID;
  }

  public void setUID(String UID) {
    this.UID = UID;
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```js
<< ? xml version = "1.0"
encoding = "utf-8" ? >
  <
  android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns : android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns: app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
tools: context = ".databaseandstorage.MainActivity" >

  <
  LinearLayout
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: orientation = "vertical" >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/date"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: ems = "10"
android: inputType = "date"
android: text = "YYYY.MM.DD.HH.MM" / >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/field2"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: ems = "10"
android: inputType = "textPersonName"
android: text = "Field 2" / >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/field3"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: ems = "10"
android: inputType = "textPersonName"
android: text = "Field 3" / >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/field4"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: ems = "10"
android: inputType = "textPersonName"
android: text = "Field 4" / >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/button"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: onClick = "Send"
android: text = "Button" / >


  <
  /LinearLayout> <
  /android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I did try to make an Array, but it was a total failure, because when I was pressing the button, it was generating random text configuration without stop. It filled thousands of lines. The code for the array was:

```js
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;



public class Array {
  public static String getUID() {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").push();
    String[] urlArray = databaseReference.toString().split("/");
    return urlArray[urlArray.length - 1];
  }

}
```

So can anyone please help me to:
1. Add the text in the database as an array with every click on "Button"
2. Use the date from EditText as the name of each child in Firebase database.

Answer (score 3):

**@Christopher Rivera** has the best answer use this

```
   DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd_hhmm a");
   String date = format.format(new Date());  

   long d = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
   String date = format.format(new Date(d));  
// result will be 20180227_1011 PM
```

or use android date picker [link](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-datepickerdialog-on-edittext-click-event/)

Comment: Thank you @Salman500, This is a step closer to what I want. I have tried the code and I found out that the year is with small "y". The problem now is that this date is taken from the current one. How do I make it to take the date from the EditText box?

Comment: i don't understand can you please explain

Comment: Okay. So, now the child in the database has this date and hour (201802277_0622 PM), which is the current date that I can read on my computer. Instead of that, that date should to be one that I write in the first box in the layout (e.g. a date in the future). For example, if I write the date 20201203_0123PM in that first box, that's what it should appear in the database.

Comment: so you want your previous data when you are in future according to my my solution it will return only current date

Comment: Yeah. But I just figured it out

Answer (score 2):

the main idea is that you will have to update these lines:

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    getValues();
    /*String UID = Array.getUID();
    myRef.child(UID).setValue(user);*/
    myRef.child("Date").setValue(user);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  }
```

to something like this:

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    getValues();
    String dateValue = "20180606_6PM";
    myRef.child(dateValue).setValue(user);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  }
```

and you have to calculate somehow that new dateValue string

and instead of doing it in the onDataChange method you should do it in a buttonClickListener

```
 send_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             String dateValue = "20180606_6PM";
    myRef.child(dateValue).setValue(user);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         }
     });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wrote it out of `onDataChange` like you suggested and it works nice and clean, but I don't really know how to switch from manually adding `20180606_6PM`  to something automatic by using the date from the EditText and with iteration on each click

Comment: google java simpleDateFormat on how to changed a date object to a string that you can use